# Filtrar datos repetidos de un combobox

Tags: c#, sql, .net

Tengo un DataTable conectado a un SP (stored procedure), este DataTable tiene una función para cargar un ComboBox de datos (LoadComboBox), pero siempre me manda a llamar varias ciudades repetidas (Ejemplo: Juan - Buenos aires,  Pedro - Buenos aires) y en el ComboBox de las ciudades se repiten dos veces Buenos aíres, necesito alguna opción tipo DISTICT.

Código función LoadComboBox:

```
public static void LoadCombox(ref ComboBox Cbx, DataTable dtValues, string StrValueMember, string StrDisplayMember, string strIdParSelectedValue, ref string strDescError)
        {
            try
            {
                DataRow dtRowCountry = dtValues.NewRow();
                dtRowCountry.SetField(StrValueMember, "-1");
                dtRowCountry.SetField(StrDisplayMember, "[SELECCIONE]");
                dtValues.Rows.InsertAt(dtRowCountry, 0);

                if ((strDescError.Trim().Length == 0) && (dtValues != null) && (dtValues.Rows.Count > 0) && (dtValues.Rows.Count > 0))
                {
                    Cbx.DisplayMember = dtValues.TableName;
                    Cbx.DataSource = dtValues;
                    Cbx.ValueMember = StrValueMember;
                    Cbx.DisplayMember = StrDisplayMember;

                    if (strIdParSelectedValue != "")
                        Cbx.SelectedValue = strIdParSelectedValue;
                    else
                        Cbx.SelectedIndex = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    //Cbx.DataSource = null;
                    if (Cbx.DataSource == null)
                        Cbx.Items.Clear();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception er)
            {
                strDescError = "Error al cargar los datos del combobox";
                throw;
            }
        }
```

Función de carga de datos (En vista, dónde se debe hacer el filtrado):

```
//CARGA LOS DATOS DE GEO LOCALIZACIÓN AL FORMULARIO
        public void loadGeoLocation()
        {
            /*Country_ID =  txtCountry.Text;*/
            txtCountry.Text = Constants.Country;
            string strError = "";
            var dsResult = DaoCustomer.SearchGeoInformation(Constants.strToken, Country_ID, Depto_Name, Munic_Name);


            Functions.LoadCombox(ref cbDepartment, dsResult, "Dept_ID", "Depto_Name", "0", ref strError);
            Functions.LoadCombox(ref cbTown, dsResult, "Munic_ID", "Munic_Name", "0", ref strError);
            

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar una vista (view) a partir del DataTable (`dtValues`). Con una sola línea puedes limitar los valores de la tabla a los valores distintos de las dos columnas.

```
dtValues.DefaultView.ToTable(true, StrValueMember, StrDisplayMember);
```

El valor `true` del método `ToTable()` indica que solo quieres valores únicos. Los dos siguientes parámetros corresponden a las columnas que quieres que sean únicas. La tabla resultante solo contendrá estas dos columnas.

Quedando así:

```
if ((strDescError.Trim().Length == 0) && (dtValues != null) && (dtValues.Rows.Count > 0) && (dtValues.Rows.Count > 0))
    {
        dtValues.DefaultView.ToTable(true, StrValueMember, StrDisplayMember);
        Cbx.DisplayMember = dtValues.TableName;
        Cbx.DataSource = dtValues;
        Cbx.ValueMember = StrValueMember;
        Cbx.DisplayMember = StrDisplayMember;

        if (strIdParSelectedValue != "")
            Cbx.SelectedValue = strIdParSelectedValue;
        else
            Cbx.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        //Cbx.DataSource = null;
        if (Cbx.DataSource == null)
            Cbx.Items.Clear();
    }
```

Comment: Que tal Roger Torné, agradezco mucho tu ayuda, pero sigue sin filtrar los datos, lo hice exactamente como tu indicas, pero no filtra los datos, agradeciendo tu apoyo te adjunto el código de nuevo:

DataTable dsAuxD = new DataTable();
            dsAuxD = dsResult.Tables[0];




Functions.LoadComboxD(ref cbDepartment, dsAuxD, "Dept_ID", "Depto_Name", "0", ref strError);

Comment: He dado por descontado que para cada Depto_Name tiene un valor único de  Dept_ID. Es decir, Buenos Aires siempre tiene el mismo Dept_ID. ¿Es así?

Comment: Tienen diferente ID, por que es por cliente, si Roger Torné es de Buenos Aires, pero Juan Perez es también de Buenos Aires, ambos tienen distinto Dept_ID

Comment: ¡Y cuál `Dept_ID` quieres recuperar del Combobox? Si solo quieres el nombre de la ciudad puedes hacer `dtValues.DefaultView.ToTable(true, StrDisplayMember);` y luego `Cbx.ValueMember = StrDisplayMember;`, así el valor y el texto del combobox sería único (no repetido).

Comment: El código final que funcionó fue este:

    dsAuxD = dsAuxD.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(r => r.Field<int>("Dept_ID")).Select(g => g.First()).CopyToDataTable();
    
Se creó una DataTable temporal llamado "dsAuxD", este mismo se llena con los valores de la tabla [0] que serían los datos, se ordena y de agrupan por ID de departamento coincidente, si Buenos Aires son 3 veces, sólo toma el ID del primer Buenos Aires y ya no duplica.

Código por: Josselyn Hernandez y Daniel Rivas